# Hide label from particular UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a `view` on another `view` and make a movable `label` form right to left, problem is that `label` moves on whole `view` and i want to show it only on second `view` not on mainview.. how to hide that `label` from particular `view`??
here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.movelabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 200, 30)];    
    self.movelabel.text = @"This is my music line";
    [self.moveview addSubview:self.move];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0                                    target:self selector:@selector(LabelAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)LabelAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
        self.move.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 0, 200, 60);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.move.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 200, 60);
     }];

}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: first check where did you all label what where that show? you need to add lable on this view that you want to show. probably you main view is transperent so that show subview's label so make sure about.

Comment: I have a music page in that one song is playing i just want to show viewrs that song name  as by moving that song name  right side to left  in my second view but i am getting main view as well as second view

Comment: why you not use this : https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Answer (score 3):

If **self.move** is label then set **clipsToBounds** property of its superview to **yes**

i.e

```
self.move.superview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

It will clip if self.move goes out of bounds of its superview.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

to hide  `UILabel` 
use :-

```
yourLbl.hidden = YES;
[yourLbl setHidden:YES];
```

or to remove

```
[yourLbl removeFromSuperview];
```

hope it may help you.